# Did dinosaurs have more than one brain? If so, why?

Tags: zoology, anatomy

I once remember reading (15 years ago) that dinosaurs had two brains. One for their head and another one for their digestive functions. What is the current opinion on this theory? Has more evidence become available?

Comment: the enteric nervous system (which humans also have) has been called "second brain" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enteric_nervous_system , but of course doesn't form an actual brain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that at one time it was thought that a "gap" in the skeleton of a *Stegosaurus* was a space for another brain. This is now thought to be a storage space for extra food.

Googling your question brings up a number of answers along these lines:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stegosaurus#%22Second_brain%22
- https://dinosaurs.about.com/od/dinosaurdiscovery/tp/dinoblunders.htm
- https://wiki.answers.com/Q/Did_a_dinosaur_have_two_brains

Comment: Oh so it was a stegosaurus. Any current scientific findings that you are aware of?

Comment: nice question - another childhood myth dispelled!

Answer (score 2):

This is a myth based on comments about the stegosaurus from a paleontologist in the 1800s. How it managed to persist is really beyond all logical reason but for a time it somehow managed to be accepted enough by the mainstream that it was even taught in school! You can still find this ‘fact’ online- just another reminder not to believe everything you read on the internet. Dinosaurs did not have 2 brains. There is an enlarged space that is likely to have housed glycogen- a characteristic shared by many birds. There is also a possibility that this area simply housed increased muscle and nerve mass, as in other living creatures signifying there back limbs were stronger and used more often than their front. Either way-no 2nd brain here. 
Google dinosaur 2 brain myth for a quick jump to the Smithsonian, a reputable source covering the myth, it’s origins, pervasiveness, and both possibilities mentioned above. Cheers!

Comment: It would be great if you can add the Smithsonian link in your answer. Cuts short one googling step :) Can you also please add a reference for the glycogen storage?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that some big dinosaurs got a second neuron group near their back legs to overcome some nerves signal delay problems. Not sure about that.

Comment: Could you add some citations or references to substantiate your answer?

Comment: I can't. I saw that on TV, it was a documentary from the BBC i guess.

Comment: A [small talk about nerves delay in dinosaurs](http://insciences.org/article.php?article_id=9238). Not talking about brains, but still interesting.

Comment: Given that baleen whales, larger than any dinosaur, apparently do not suffer any neural delay problems, it is difficult to see why dinosaurs would have such.